# Can't execute page with "main" but working with explicit path

Tags: javascript, node.js

*I'm a nooob at Node so it's likely due to my ignorance that I'm doing something else than what I think I am. Due to the same reason, I haven't seen anything helpful when I googled the issue.*

When I'm running my page like this

> node app/index.js

it works and displays the right text in the browser as I head to *localhost:3001*. Then I tried to specify in the JSON file the path like this

> "start": "app/index.js", ...

and executing node without any arguments. My understanding was that since there's no arguments given, the program till look up something in the configuration file.

I noticed that when I specify the path explicitly, I get nothing in the console and it "hangs". But when I go with *node* alone, there's a bracket like if it's waiting for something. No idea what, though...

For some reason it doesn't and the page can't be shown. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`start` command in your `package.json` file should looks something like this - 
`"start": "node app/index.js"`. And then to run it you need to execute `npm start`. `node` command without parameters just stars node-repl. Read more about npm and `package.json` at [npmjs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json).

The `main` parameter in your `package.json` is used as the entry point to your package. To run different scripts you should use `node [path_to_script]`.

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module's exports object will be returned.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I meant, however, to ask about *main*, not *start*. It says so in the title but in the question I pasted in wrong thing. Sorry for the confusion - I'm very new to all this. Care to take another look at it, please?

Comment: As I know `nodemon` without parameters executes `main` file, but I don't think it's what you are looking for.

Comment: I ran it in PowerShell but the command wasn't recognized. Maybe it's because I'm on Windows 10. Or maybe I'm just misunderstanding the point of *main*. Are you saying that the **proper** way to run my web application (in local host) is to execute *npm start*?

Comment: Yes. Specify command in package.json `..."start": "node app/index.js"...` and then just run `npm start`.

Comment: Awesome info. It seems so counter-intuitive to me because NPM is just a package manager and it's Node that's supposed to run the app. Of course, I do see how it executes the *node path* thingy but it feel like going over the river to get water, hehe. Answer accepted.